# Make PrimeReact Tree of custom component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, primereact

I am really new to react/UI but I have gone through basics of how it renders. I know about this Tree component in "primereact"(https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/) but i would like to know is it possible to make a tree of Buttons ot custom component using primereact Tree component.

TIA

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @c-chavez, thanks, I have tried rendering PrimeReact's Tree component with many combinations according to their document. But issue is I dont see a way/option for me to have a way to pass my contents instead of predefined keys like label, icon, children[]. Some way i could pass my own <div> for each TreeNode. Is it even possible?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible because of the data it receives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodeTemplate property to create the custom nodes;
https://primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/tree Please see 'Templating' section in doc